# LINQ creates query leaving "From" clause empty

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got an mvc3 application with the following code:

```
public static List<ApprovalDTO> ConvertToDTO(IQueryable<REGISTER> r2, GMIEntities db, User user)
{
    List<ApprovalDTO> rta = new List<ApprovalDTO>();

    r2= r2.Where(r => r.APPROVAL.STATE1.DESC_STATE == Constants.ON_HOLD);
    String sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)r2.OrderBy(o => o.ANALYSIS.ANALYSIS_DATE)).ToTraceString();


   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sql);  }
```

r2 is constructed in another method using:

```
IQueryable<REGISTER> r2 = db.REGISTER;
r2 = r2.OrderByDescending(r => r.WEIGHING);
            return r2;
```

Thus, resulting in this query:

```
SELECT
"Extent1".-SOME INFO-
FROM  ( SELECT  
 -SOME INFO- FROM     ORDER BY "ANALYSIS_DATE" ASC ) "MYSCHEMA"."REGISTER"  ORDER BY "ANALYSIS_DATE" ASC ) "Extent1"
```

This obviously gives an "Invalid table name" error when executing the query, since LINQ isn't filling the FROM clause for extent1
What could be causing this?

Comment: How is `r2` constructed before this is called?

Comment: Sorry, just added it!

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Oracle data provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, after reinstalling Visual Studio the problem was solved